# Python GTK EntryCompletion select first result when Intro

Tags: python, gtk3

Using Python 2.7, Ubuntu 16.04, Gtk3 (`gi.repository`). I have an `Entry` with an associated `EntryCompletion` and a `ListStore`. I would like to let the user *autoselect* the first result when pressing the Enter/Intro/Return key, without having to use the arrow keys to select an item, and then press Enter. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `EntryCompletion.set_inline_completion(True)` ?

This may not be exactly what you were looking for as it will not select the complete first match. However, if you type far enough (to only have one choice), you can press Enter to autocomplete the rest.

Tell me your thoughts on this and/or more details on what you are trying to do. Maybe there is another way to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: This could be a partial solution of what I want. Anyway, using `EntryCompletion.set_inline_completion(True)` looks not to work as expected (or at least as I think it should do by your explanation). This is a screenshot of the result: http://imgur.com/1g46JJA (the folders shown below are not part of the result; there is only one result).

Comment: Now I am confused as to how the search is working. Are you using a `CompletionMatchFunc`? This affects the inline completion, I think... Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Yes, I am using a custom matcher. Here is a simplified version of my code: https://gist.github.com/okelet/2980004bbf4e04629cd64c82f11a1d2b. I have tested the `set_inline_completion` without my custom matcher, and then the behaviour is as you say, but not with my code... My intention is that when the user, with the code in that gist, types "folder 1 2", that gives 3 results (or even if the search returns only 1 result), if the user press Enter, the `match-action` should be triggered using the first result, or something similar.

Comment: Hmmm... It might be possible to keep track of the first search matched and then trigger the `match-action` manually by detecting the Enter key pressed within the `Entry`. Let me think...

Comment: It will not be easy to trigger the `match-action` with all the variables. However, you can keep track of the first search with some code in your custom matcher. Reset the first search with the `Entry.changed` signal. Set the function/feature you want with the `Entry.activate` signal, which gets fired when you press Enter. Let me know if this works or not.